# sendKeys is NOT working for input text box with SLIDER, but it works for CLEAR the input field ( selenium java )

Tags: java, html, selenium, slider, input-field

Please help me here, I have to  feed the input in the mortage amount input field. Actually, the input text field is associated with slider. But i works for CLEARING the input field, not working for SENDKEYS.
Also iput field which is not associated with slider, SENDKEYS is working fine.

For example,

```
@FindBy(xpath = "//*[contains(text(),'Mortgage Amount')]/following::input[@id='name'][1]")
public WebElement mortageAmountInput;

mortageAmountInput.clear();            -> It works for clearing the input text field

mortageAmountInput.sendKeys("300000");  -> It is not working for clearing the input text field
```

This the webpage where i am facing this issue: https://www.coastcapitalsavings.com/calculators/mortgage-calculator

For your information, https://calculator.coastcapitalsavings.com/ITSCredit.External/CCS/ITSCredit.CCS.UI.External/calculator/MT This page is inside the frame of main page --> https://www.coastcapitalsavings.com/calculators/mortgage-calculator.

Below is the HTML:

```
<div class="custom-slider" id="slider-container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8 col-md-8 col-lg-8">
            <span class="generic-title">Mortgage Amount</span>
            <!----><span class="info-tooltip ng-star-inserted" data-balloon="The total amount of the mortgage."></span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
            <input onlynumber="true" id="name" type="text" class="ng-valid ng-dirty ng-touched">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
            <div id="slider-distance" slider="">
                <div>
                    <div inverse="" style="width: 96.5966%;"></div>
                    <div range="" style="width: 3.4034%;"></div>
                    <div thumb="" style="left: 3.32039%;"></div>
                    <div sign="" style="left: 3.4034%;">
                        <span id="value">3.4034034034034035</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <input tabindex="0" type="range" min="10000" max="10000000" step="1" data-slider-id="sliderMortgageAmount" id="sliderMortgageAmount" data-tryxpath-element="0">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: does it showing any exception?

Comment: actually there is no exception. It grabs the default value which is set. So it moves to next line without failing it.

Comment: Can you  use explict wait with expected conditions in between clear and send keys ?

Comment: yes i used that no clue

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot 'SendKeys', try 'SetValue':

```
(JavascriptExecutor)driver.executeScript("arguments[0].value='300000';", mortageAmountInput);
```

Comment: no i already tried it, it didn't work. Actually, CLEAR is working, SENDKEYS is not working.

Comment: Ok, so try emulate user actions: Clear(); Click(); SendKeys();

Answer (score 0):

I have used Action class and i am able to clear and change the value. I hope you switching frames before any actions.

```
 driver.switchTo().frame("ifrm_13536");
```

> Option 1 Code snippet

```
 Actions action = new Actions(driver); 
        action.moveToElement(mortageAmountInput).doubleClick()
        .sendKeys(Keys.DELETE)
        .sendKeys("5000")
        .build().perform();
```

Option 2-In my case .clear function was not working and sendkeys was

```
 mortageAmountInput.sendKeys(Keys.BACK_SPACE);    
 mortageAmountInput.sendKeys(Keys.BACK_SPACE); 
 mortageAmountInput.sendKeys("5000");
```

[image]